# iphone - How do I get the 1st and 2nd byte in a NSData object?

Tags: iphone, nsdata

I have a NSData object which is supposed to work like a byte array.

I need to get the `1st and 2nd bytes in the NSData`, but don't know how.

If I have a byte array in Java, I can easily get those via `barray[0] and barray[1]`, but how do I do it for NSData?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:"abc" length:3];
const unsigned char* bytes = [data bytes];
NSLog(@"%c %c",bytes[0],bytes[1]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code,

```
    NSUInteger len = [data length];
Byte *byteData = (Byte*)malloc(len);
memcpy(byteData, [data bytes], len);
```

now `byteData[0]` will work.

Comment: If you really only need the first two bytes, don't memcpy the whole thing, set `len` to 2. And then free the malloced data when done. Or just use @Jano's no-copy version.